# Default speed parameter for Iso-Area polygons in QNEAT3 plugin

Tags: qgis, isochrone

In the answer for a similar question ([QNEAT3 plugin and Iso-Area polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377629/qneat3-plugin-and-iso-area-polygons/439140#439140)), it is stated that in QNEAT3 “You can either define a default speed that is used for all graph edges (eg. streets) the time based routing (fastest path) or you can add edge specific speed values inside a field in your graph (measured in KM/H if your coordinate system is in Meters, otherwise MPH, etc.) and use this field for the fastest path calculation.”

My question is, if i can combine the 'default speed' value with a speed value by segment taken from a network layer (this assumes that the 'default speed parameter is rather used for determining the cost of the 'network entry', i.e. the distance/speed from the starting point to the next available network line/vertice. At least the plugin documentation says so) Or does the 'default speed' value override the speed values taken from the network layer? The description of the plugin doesn’t really enlighten me there.

I want to take the speed of network segments from an attribute in the network layer and additionally define a speed for the entry of points not exactly lying on that network (e.g. centroids of buildings lying a few metres off the street but also buildings where a road is missing and a straight line distance should be taken as network entry. Is the straight line distance taken as a reference there?)

Comment: My first idea would be to test it, make an experiment: run the with the same paramenters, once with and once without default speed. Is there a difference in output?

Comment: As I came across another issue related to qneat3 with artefacts between Isochrone far apart (see also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385265/making-nonoverlapping-service-area-polygons-using-qneat3-service-area-polygon-e) - I stopped using it. But to answer the question: it actually makes a difference if you define default speed and also have a speed field - I. E. Default speed is then used to determine access time from a disconnected start point to the next network node.